# Complex rsync filtering (includes and excludes)

Tags: linux, unix, rsync

I got directories and files that look like this

```
/1.txt
/2.txt
/3.txt
/20170407_000000
    /config
       file1.txt
    /logs
       file1.txt
    /nav
       file1.txt
    /schedule
       file1.txt
       file2.txt
       file3.txt
    /soh
       file1.txt
    /tracks
       file1.txt
/20170407_120000
    /config
       file1.txt
    /logs
       file1.txt
    /nav
       file1.txt
    /schedule
       file1.txt
       file2.txt
       file3.txt
    /soh
       file1.txt
    /tracks
       file1.txt
/20170408_000000
    /config
       file1.txt
    /logs
       file1.txt
    /nav
       file1.txt
    /schedule
       file1.txt
       file2.txt
       file3.txt
    /soh
       file1.txt
    /tracks
       file1.txt
/20170408_120000
    /config
       file1.txt
    /logs
       file1.txt
    /nav
       file1.txt
    /schedule
       file1.txt
       file2.txt
       file3.txt
    /soh
       file1.txt
    /tracks
       file1.txt
/20170409_000000
    /config
       file1.txt
    /logs
       file1.txt
    /nav
       file1.txt
    /schedule
       file1.txt
       file2.txt
       file3.txt
    /soh
       file1.txt
    /tracks
       file1.txt
/20170409_120000
    /config
       file1.txt
    /logs
       file1.txt
    /nav
       file1.txt
    /schedule
       file1.txt
       file2.txt
       file3.txt
    /soh
       file1.txt
    /tracks
       file1.txt
/20170410_000000
    /config
       file1.txt
    /logs
       file1.txt
    /nav
       file1.txt
    /schedule
       file1.txt
       file2.txt
       file3.txt
    /soh
       file1.txt
    /tracks
       file1.txt
/20170410_120000
    /config
       file1.txt
    /logs
       file1.txt
    /nav
       file1.txt
    /schedule
       file1.txt
       file2.txt
       file3.txt
    /soh
       file1.txt
    /tracks
       file1.txt
/20170411_000000
    /config
       file1.txt
    /logs
       file1.txt
    /nav
       file1.txt
    /schedule
       file1.txt
       file2.txt
       file3.txt
    /soh
       file1.txt
    /tracks
       file1.txt
/20170411_120000
    /config
       file1.txt
    /logs
       file1.txt
    /nav
       file1.txt
    /schedule
       file1.txt
       file2.txt
       file3.txt
    /soh
       file1.txt
    /tracks
       file1.txt
/20170412_000000
    /config
       file1.txt
    /logs
       file1.txt
    /nav
       file1.txt
    /schedule
       file1.txt
       file2.txt
       file3.txt
    /soh
       file1.txt
    /tracks
       file1.txt
/20170412_120000
    /config
       file1.txt
    /logs
       file1.txt
    /nav
       file1.txt
    /schedule
       file1.txt
       file2.txt
       file3.txt
    /soh
       file1.txt
    /tracks
       file1.txt
```

I only want to copy the 20170409_*/schedule, 20170410_*/schedule, 20170411_*/schedule folders and contents.

This mostly works:

```
 rsync -avhr --progress  --include="/20170409_*/schedule/" --include="/20170410_*/schedule/" --include="/20170411_*/schedule/"  --exclude="/*/*"  /source/dateTimeDirectories/ /destination/dateTimeDirectories/
```

However this also copies the following:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
20170407_000000/
20170407_120000/
20170408_000000/
20170408_120000/
...
20170412_000000/
20170412_120000/
```

How do I omit the files and the dateTimeFolders I haven't included and only get the dateTimeFolder's schedule folder that I have included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the situation correctly, you need to add the option `--prune-empty-dirs` (in short, `-m`) to your command. Those directories are not matched by the exclude rule which exludes their children, so they are copied by default. `-m` prevents this. If you want to prevent other files to be copied, you must add specific exclude rules for them. For instance, the files `1.txt`, `2.txt` and so on can be excluded by `--exclude=/*.txt`. All in all, your command should look as follows:

```
 rsync -avhr \
   --progress \
   --prune-empty-dirs \
   --include="/20170409_*/schedule/" \
   --include="/20170410_*/schedule/" \
   --include="/20170411_*/schedule/" \
   --exclude="/*.txt" \
   --exclude="/*/*"  \
   /source/dateTimeDirectories/ \
   /destination/dateTimeDirectories/
```

Comment: you sir are a god among mortals!

Comment: actually. testing in the real environment I found some more problems. I have updated the explanation above. Your help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: @lr100 I have updated my answer to deal with the `*.txt` files in the source root.

Comment: if I use --exclude="/*.*" will it exclude all files (not just .txt)?

Comment: @lr100 `/*.*` will match all files _and directories_ with a dot in the name.